# Monte Carlo sampling of particle system for velocity dependent potential

Tags: monte-carlo, random-sampling

When sampling configurations of point particles in statistical mechanics by means of (Markov chain) Monte Carlo, we may work with a potential that only depends on the positions of the particles, and to generate new states we assign probabilities to configurations according to the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution), which (to my understanding) arises from the (temperature dependent) distribution of velocities of the particles.

What can we do when we want to work with a (generalized) potential that also depends on the velocity of the particles? I would assume that in that case we need to consider the velocity of each particle, along with its position, to be part of the state, that statistics alone doesn't suffice anymore. Or does it? How do we assign relative probabilities to different configurations? Can we still use the Boltzmann distribution?

Comment: Just to clear my confusion, but isn't a temperature dependency exactly a velocity dependency on a microscopic level?

Comment: @sonystarmap It is the *distribution* that depends on the temperature, not the potential energy of the state. I am interested in *potentials* that depend on velocities. Moreover I do not want to restrict to any particular kind of dependence. Also note that temperature is roughly equal to the *average* speed of the particles, so even if the *potential energy* would depend on the velocities, but in a non-additive way, the potential would not be a function of the temperature.

Comment: I'm not sure if the [Maxwell Boltzman Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) is of any help?

Comment: @sonystarmap Well, the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution describes the distribution of speeds in an ideal gas rather than the distribution of states. Moreover it assumes no potential energy at all (except for a mechanism for instantaneous energy and momentum exchange)

Comment: One could perform hybrid MD/MC. The procedure here is (1) thermalize particles according to maxwellian distribution (2) run 50-100 NVE time steps trajectory (3) accept or reject whole trajectory based off change in hamiltonian = delta_potential energy + delta_kinetic energy